# Spacebar for Vim mapleader

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vim

I am wanting to use the spacebar for my mapleader, but the only problem is that every time I use the spacebar while typing it is trying to be my leader and causing a slight delay. Is there anyway to overcome this issue?

Right now I have:

```
let mapleader="\<SPACE>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a literal "space" character in the quotes:

`let mapleader=" "`

Comment: Yes this did help. I still do see something show up in the bottom right corner, but I think the delay comes from YouCompleteMe trying to autocomplete everything. Thank you